# Push Notifications in Smartface App Studio

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to implement Pust Notifications using Smartface App Studio.
I followed the link: http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/push-notifications/ 
But, i stuck up with following.
1. Where can i find the devices which are registered with their device tokens by Notifications.remote.registerForPushNotifications() method.
2. How to get access_token to push the notifications from smartface api.

Can any one help me to figured out these? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For IOS below code works for me. I think android have changed for 4.5

```
var registerParsePush = new SMF.Net.WebClient({
        httpMethod : "POST",
        URL : "https://api.parse.com/1/installations",
        contentType : "application/json",
        requestHeaders : ["X-Parse-Application-Id:     f5Y4tmDdKOYm5YdKDdDV8W6LDfviqFaCfhMgmxx", "X-Parse-REST-API-Key:     PqbhEDYJcXP3xWmWRB6PBuzfIz4OIq0tK4V3dpxx", "Content-Type: application/json"],
        onSyndicationSuccess : function (e) {},
        onServerError : function (e) {}
    });


Notifications.remote.registerForPushNotifications({
    OnSuccess : function () {
        var pushToken = Notifications.remote.token;
        var req = {
            "deviceType" : "ios",
            "deviceToken" : pushToken,
            "channels" : [
                ""
            ]
        };
        registerParsePush.requestString = JSON.stringify(req);
        registerParsePush.run(true);
    },
    OnFailure : function () {}
});
```

Comment: I am trying smartface api push notifications not with parse. For that, we require access_token from smartface api and place where we can see all registered devices (not from parse).

Comment: You can change webclient url to your server to record tokens

Comment: Thanks Alex. But, where can i get smartface api access_tocken to push the notifications?

Comment: var pushToken = Notifications.remote.token; will give you the access_token

Comment: Hope this is for device token which is registered. 
I need the access_token to send the notifications from smartface api (http://api.smartface.io/api/PushNotification/Send/{access_token})